# Как оптимально и эффективно размещать клиентские JS-скрипты в PHP-страницах?

Tags: php, javascript, скрипт, include

Существуют ли какие-то оптимальные и эффективные способы добавления JS-скриптов в страницы, генерируемые PHP?

Пока мне удалось найти только одну [рекомендацию](https://www.collectiveray.com/wp/tips/add-javascript-to-wordpress), применимую к WordPress. В другой [статье](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_dupes) автор предлагает использовать какую-то функцию `<?php insertScript("menu.js") ?>`, но не приводит её кода.

Приведу пример: у моего тестового сайта есть три страницы: index.php, orders.php и users.php. Каждая из страниц требует подключения обязательных скриптов Bootstrap 4, которые нужно размещать внизу страницы перед закрываемым тэгом `</body>`.

> Здесь и далее я убрал атрибут `type="text/javascript"` чтобы получилось короче.

```
    <!--основные скрипты Bootstrap 4-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Далее требования разнятся. В дополнение к основным скриптам, каждая из страниц "хочет" еще собственный скрипт: index.js, orders.js или users.js, который может идти или до, или после основных скриптов. Например, вот так должны выглядеть скрипты в странице users.php:

```
    <!--скрипт HASH-функций-->
    <script src="js/sha512.js"></script>

    <!--основные скрипты Bootstrap 4-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--скрипты только для этой страницы или другие скрипты-->
    <script src="js/myengine.js"></script>
    <script src="js/users.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ну и давайте усложним пример: в странице orders.php будут ссылки на другие скрипты и еще и сам скрипт, выполняющий действия при загрузке документа. Этот скрипт должен стоять самым последним. Низ страницы orders.php выглядит вот так:

```
    <!--мой собственный скрипт-->
    <script src="js/blahblah.js"></script>

    <!--основные скрипты Bootstrap 4-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--скрипты Bootstrap DataTables-->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <!--скрипты только для этой страницы или другие скрипты-->
    <script src="js/myengine.js"></script>
    <script src="js/orders.js"></script>

    <!--ну, и бонус-->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
      } );
    <script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> **Вот как всё это правильно "писать" в каждую страницу?**
>   *Динамически. Правильно. Оптимально. Эффективно.*

Генерировать это все через `include 'inc/footer.php';` не совсем удобно и совсем (как мне кажется) неправильно, потому что контент в футере статичный.

Еще приходит в голову группировка скриптов *по назначению* и создание простеньких функций в include-файле. Например, файл clientscripts.php:

```
<?php
function mainBootstrapScripts() { ?>
    <!--основные скрипты Bootstrap 4-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php
};
function dataTablesBootsrapScripts() {
?>
    <!--скрипты Bootstrap DataTables-->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<?php
};
?>
```

Но ведь есть одиночные скрипты, которые никак не поддаются группировке. Тогда, по сути, на каждый скрипт писать отдельную PHP-функцию?

Еще можно создать большую PHP-функцию, принимающую массив в качестве параметра: `clientScripts(['coreBS4scrips', 'BS4DT', 'users.js']);` Этот вариант кажется мне наиболее оптимальным. Только пока непонятно как соблюдать последовательности и не нарушать зависимости.

Есть ли какие-то best practices?
Как все это управляется в больших проектах?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81190/discussion-on-question-by-interface-unknown-----).

Comment: В больших проектах php только для апишки используется. И все js в одном файле. Вообще я бы все скрипты засунул в общий подвал и забыл о них)

Answer (score 0):

После более чем недельного исследования я пришел к выводу, что *конкретно моя задача* решается написанием небольшой PHP-функции, которая принимает в качестве параметра массив, элементами которого являются "ключи" скриптов. Вот моё решение.

> **csscripst.php** (Client-Side Scripts)

```
//массив со всеми используемыми скриптами
$clientScripts = array(

  'jquery-3.3.1.min' =>
    '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>',

  'bootstrap.min' =>
    '<script  src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>',

  'jquery.dataTables.min' =>
    '<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>',

  'auth/users' =>
    '<script src="js/auth/users.js"></script>'
);

//функция выборки необходимых скриптов из массива
function clientScripts(array $s) {
  global $clientScripts;
  $scripts = '';
  foreach ($s as $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $clientScripts)) {
      $scripts = $scripts.$clientScripts[$v]."\n";
    };
  };
  echo $scripts;
};
```

> **users.php**

Функция вызывается в самом конце страницы (перед `</body></html>`):

```
include_once 'inc/csscripts.go';
...

<?php
pageFooter();
clientScripts(['jquery-3.3.1.min', 'bootstrap.min', 'auth/users']);
endOfPage();
?>
```